# I want to get result json from goeuro api

Tags: java, json, node.js, api

I am developing API in java to get json from [GoEuro API](http://www.goeuro.com/GoEuroAPI/rest/api/v3/search) is available at [github](https://github.com/evgenTraytyak/goeuro-api). i want to know parameter i need to send with POST method and get result as json and combined with my custom logic.

Here is my java code to call api.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JsonEncodeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.goeuro.com/GoEuroAPI/rest/api/v3/search?departure_fk=318781&departure_date=16%2F04%2F2017&arrival_fk=380553&trip_type=one-way&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&from_filter=Coventry+%28COV%29%2C+United+Kingdom&to_filter=London%2C+United+Kingdom&travel_mode=bus&ab_test_enabled=");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

//          conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream()), "UTF-8"));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

I am not good in nodejs. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you getting any error? Can you explain what is your expected output?

Comment: First of all i am not sure, i have attached required param. Also output should be in json string.

Comment: are you getting this error in response? : {
  "message": "400: Bad Request",
  "errorClass": "InvalidRequestEntityException",
  "description": "Validation failed",
  "items": [
    "SearchQuery.locale may not be null",
    "SearchQuery.domain may not be null",
    "SearchQuery.departurePosition may not be null",
    "SearchQuery.outboundDate may not be null",
    "SearchQuery.resultFormat may not be null",
    "SearchQuery.arrivalPosition may not be null",
    "SearchQuery.currency may not be null"
  ]
}

Comment: I tried your http post request in Postman and got this. Here is the list of search parameter that you are not sending but those fields must be validated.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan i have tried with parameter you suggested. but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, i found my answers from github issue.

Here are required params and there expected json format.

```
{
   "arrivalPosition":{
      "positionId":380244
},
   "currency":"EUR",
   "departurePosition":{
      "positionId":380553
   },
   "domain":"com",
   "inboundDate":"2017-04-19T00:00:00.000",
   "locale":"en",
   "outboundDate":"2017-04-18T00:00:00.000",
   "passengers":[
      {
         "age":18,
         "rebates":[]
      }
   ],
   "resultFormat":{
      "splitRoundTrip":true
   },
   "searchModes":[
      "directbus"   
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the url needs to be only this `http://www.goeuro.com/GoEuroAPI/rest/api/v3/search`

Then you need to add parameters using params in request.

Your if response != 200 has to be after you make the request.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.goeuro.com/GoEuroAPI/rest/api/v3/search);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            String urlParameters = "departure_fk=318781&departure_date=16%2F04%2F2017&arrival_fk=380553&trip_type=one-way&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&from_filter=Coventry+%28COV%29%2C+United+Kingdom&to_filter=London%2C+United+Kingdom&travel_mode=bus&ab_test_enabled=";

            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
```